# Selecting and entering information into web forms with Python 3.X

Tags: python, automation, mechanize, python-3.3

In a program I am creating in Python 3.3.2, I need to have the program log into my account by selecting forms on the webpage, entering information to the forms, and submitting the information.  Python 2.X versions have mechanize for this, but I would not like to have to port the program to be compatible with 2.X. Is there a library like Mechanize for 3.X or a way I could code this myself without an extensive knowledge of all the built-in web libraries?

Answer (score 0):

One popular library/mechanism is [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). It has a [Python API](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) that supports Python 3, and a whole bunch of features that would be quite useful for your project. Good luck!